# Add CSS change on touch start for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, phonegap-build, touch-event

I'm attempting to change the CSS of a link before the app navigates to another page.
I've previously added an `ontouchstart` event to the link element to greatly speed up navigation in the app. The problem is that the event fires and app navigates before the CSS can change.

**What are some ways I could provide user feedback before the page changes?**

Additional notes:

- This is a SPA constructed using AngularJS and PhoneGap Build.
- I discovered that using `button:active` will only fire after the button is clicked so the page would navigate before the CSS changes.
- I believe this will need to be tested on a touch-screen device to see the effect.
- This is my first question on here so please be gentle :)

Here is some example code:

**HTML**

```
<a class="button" ontouchstart="goTo('#!/stats', 'buttonActive', this);" onclick="goTo('#!/stats', 'buttonActive', this);">STATS</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #000000; 
    color: dodgerblue;
    font-size: 4vmin;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 7vmin;
    border: 0.75vmin solid dodgerblue;
    border-radius: 1vmin;
    height: 8vh;
    width: 40vmin;
    padding: 2vmin;
    margin: 5vmin auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.buttonActive {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
}
```

**JS**

```
function goTo (location, addClass, elem) {
    elem.className += addClass;
    window.location.href = location;
}
```

Comment: maybe button:focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `ontouchend` instead of `ontouchstart`. This allowed for the CSS to change while the user's finger is pushed down and the page will not navigate until the user releases his/her finger.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just add a slight delay to the goTo function's window.location.href call. This would give the css time to update before the new file is requested. It might look something like this:

```
function goTo (location, addClass, elem) {
  elem.className += addClass;
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    window.location.href = location;
  }, 250);
}
```

That would make for a 250-millisecond delay...likely enough time to allow the css to update and your viewers to recognize the change before the new file request is initiated.

Comment: Though this is would work, it would defeat the whole purpose of using 'ontouchstart' vs 'onclick.'